# Large file attachments to specific Google Drive folder

Tags: gmail, google-drive, gmail-attachments

In Gmail when you attach a large file to an email, it is uploaded to your Google Drive account instead and the receiver is linked to that location in your Drive.

It is annoying to me that such files are uploaded to the root of my Google Drive (#firstWorldProblems). I would prefer them to always be uploaded to a specific folder. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't specify where your attachments will be dropped. Its default behavior to end up in the root folder. The only solution (not fast tho) would be to upload such attachments onto a Drive first and then compose your email where you can select a file from your Drive with utmost comfort.